# error code enosys and err number 38 occur when I try tsudo npm install on termux in android

Tags: android, node.js, termux

I write a nodejs application and want to run it on android. I install nodejs using termux.

My device is rooted.

When I input command

```
tsudo npm install
```

the following error occur.

```
ERR! path ../json/libcli.js
ERR! code ENOSYS
ERR! errno -38
ERR! ENOSYS: function not implemented, symlink '../json5/lib/cli.js' -> 'storage/emulated/0/Download/Iot-blockchain-Std/node_modules/.bin/json5'
```

How to solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the folder to the home directory of termux. For more details, please refer to 
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134885/error-function-not-implemented-when-creating-symbolic-link

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this IS an answer. It still provides an answer if the link dies. The link merely provides _extra_ informatoin.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*